# EWS - Possible timeout?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm new to EWS so forgive me if this is obvious. I searched and could not find a solution.

I have a command line C# utility that filters emails and organizes them into folders. The app seems to work fine logically, but appears to be timing out after 15 minutes without error.

The utility connects using autodiscover:

```
private ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);

...

// Connect using credentials and autodiscover
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password, domain);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailServer);
```

Then after filtering, it loops through the results and moves the emails into the appropriate folders. Something like this:

```
...

// Create a filter to only return unread messages
SearchFilter emailFilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2));

// Retrieve the results
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(folder, emailFilter, view);
Logger.Write("Total emails to be archived: " + findResults.TotalCount);

...

try
{
    ...

    foreach (Item email in findResults)
    {

        EmailMessage emailMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, email.Id);
        emailMessage.Load();
        emailMessage.Move(folder5.Folders[0].Id);

    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Write("Exception caught while moving emails: " + ex.Message);
    throw ex;
}

...

Logger.Write("=== End Email Move Logic...");
```

My first logging output indicates that 5,000 emails should be moved, and in fact, the process begins nicely, but after 15 minutes, I see the final logging output. Indicating that everything completed. Yet, only a portion of the total 5000 get moved. Oddly, I do not see an exception or anything in the event logs.

**EDIT: 7/9/2014**

Ok, my initial problem was due to the fact that I did not notice that the FindItemsResults class uses paging! Doh! So even though it correctly reported the TotalCount (5000), when I iterated through the results, only 1000 were being processed. Not terribly intuitive to a EWS noob like me, but there you have it.

Unfortunately, I have a follow-up frustration. Based on Brad's comments below, I'm now using the ExchangeService.MoveItems method. After dealing with the paging issue, I now have a proper list of itemIds (count = 5000) that I pass to the MoveItems method. Like this:

```
 service.MoveItems(itemIds, folder5.Folders[0].Id);
```

To my surprise, only 730 emails were moved. Leaving 4270 emails unmoved. So, hoping to find a pattern, I ran it again, this time 671 emails were moved. No pattern.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've run into throttle limits on EWS before. So, assuming the requests happen concurrently (and not sure of the payload/hit frequency) you may run in to the throttle limit being hit (and therefore kicking you off the server for a period of time).

Comment: As an aside, you may want to look at [`MoveItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd635921%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx): `service.MoveItems(findResults, folder5.Folders[0].Id)`

Comment: Brad, thanks. I'll substitute that in, I had a feeling there was a better way.

Comment: Just to tie things up, I was not able to use MoveItems as you have written (unless I'm missing something) as the MoveItems method requires a list of itemIds (ie. not FindItemResults). So I had to loop through the results and extract the itemIds out into a separate list.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but just in case anybody has a similar problem:

MoveItems is subject to throttle limits too. If you run up against a limit while moving a large number of items, it will halt execution until the limits refresh, possibly causing a timeout. Make sure you iterate through the results returned by MoveItems to ensure each individual item was moved successfully, then wait / retry any that failed.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is an old thread but it was the first I found on Google so thought I would add my findings.

I coded a WPF app to help in migrating legacy Exchange public folders to Office 365 hosted Exchange and have been experiencing timeouts when searching using the FindItems method. Specifically I was searching over a date range for date sent in a public folder and then copying the items found to the Office 365 public folder. If we used a large date range then the FindItems call would timeout.

What has fixed it for us is to set the Timeout value for the ExchangeService, the default is 100000 milliseconds, so we just added another 0 to test the possible solution. Hey presto we were able to use much larger date ranges.

```
                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
            ExchangeService o365 = new ExchangeService();
            switch (strArgs[6])
            {
                case "0":
                    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
                    break;
                case "1":
                    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
                    break;
                case "5":
                    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
                    break;
            }

            
            int nCount = 0;
            // Connect to on-premises Exchange Server
            callback(nCount, "Connecting to on-premises Exchange Server, please wait....", 0, true, mailItem);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(strArgs[0], strArgs[1]);
            if (!useUrl)
                service.AutodiscoverUrl(strArgs[2], RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
            else
                service.Url = new Uri(strArgs[10] + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            service.Timeout = 1000000;
            callback(nCount, "Connected to on-premises Exchange Server, please wait....", 0, true, mailItem);
            // Connect to Office 365 Exchange Server
            callback(nCount, "Connecting to Office 365 Exchange Server, please wait....", 0, true, mailItem);
            o365.Credentials = new WebCredentials(strArgs[7], strArgs[8]);
            o365.AutodiscoverUrl(strArgs[9], RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
            callback(nCount, "Connected to Office 365 Exchange Server, please wait....", 0, true, mailItem);
```

We are using a paging value of 500.
The source Exchange version is Exchange 2007 SP1.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts are normal for search queries, especially for large folders.
What happens is Exchange does not keep live indexes to respond to just any search query you can build, so it times out the response and keeps indexing.
If you try to issue the same query later it will succeed. Unfortunately Exchange does not provide information on when, just keep trying. After first page is returned further page queries will return almost immediately.

BTW this is not a throttling issue, you will get a clear error back when throttling limit is reached. Exchange 2007 just says that, 2010 and higher provides you a value of how much to wait until throttling quota will be recharged.